# calling a javascript function from a telerik RadButton

Tags: javascript, webforms, telerik, telerik-radbutton

I'm new to both WebForms and Telerik and have the following table cell:

```
<td class="gridtd">
   <telerik:RadButton ID="btnOpslaan" Text="Verder" runat="server"
    autopostback="false" OnClientClicked='<%# "return (function()
     {EditLocatie("+ Eval("_userId") + Eval("_nextViewName") + ");})" %>' />
   <telerik:RadButton ID="btnAnnuleer" Text="Terug" runat="server" CausesValidation="false" />
</td>
```

I expect a `button` which calls the described `javascript` function when I click it, but it does not. I have no idea what I am doing wrong here. I tried removing `runat="server"`, but it seems this attribute is required. Does anyone else know what the problem could be?

Comment: http://demos.telerik.com/aspnet-ajax/button/examples/clientsideevents/defaultcs.aspx

Comment: Did my answer fixed your issue?

Answer (score 0):

It seems that the javascript code you are generating is incorrect.

Try to replace the contents of `OnClientClicked='...'` with
`OnClientClicked='<%# "return EditLocatie(\'" + Eval("_userId") + Eval("_nextViewName") + "\');" %>'`.

This should generate a code similar to this:
`return EditLocatie('... the result of Eval _userId + Eval _nextViewName...');`